# CSV to Layer from a Delimited Text File in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

enter image description hereI am importing a CSV file into QGIS using the official instructions on their page: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html. For some reason, the x & y coordinates are showing up on QGIS in the wrong place. I have checked the coordinates in Google Maps and they correctly present the locations I want to see in Tanzania.

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong by reviewing the attachment.

[image]

Comment: I think the _official_ instructions are from the [QGIS docs](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#delimited-text-files) itself but the tutorials by Ujaval Gandhi (which you linked) are indeed brilliant!

Comment: What CRS are you using when it prompts you for one?

Comment: @Vesanto unfortunately, QGIS does not prompt by default.

Comment: WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator

Comment: The coordinates in column B and C are in degrees, not Mercator.

Comment: So the problem is the CRS I am choosing? Which CRS should I select?

Comment: EPSG:4326 WGS84.

Answer (score 1):

Under `Settings -> Options, CRS tab`, you can select that you want to get asked for the CRS of new layers by checking `Prompt for CRS`.

The data in your table seems to be in degrees, so `EPSG:4326` might be the right one.

The **Project** CRS can be different from that. For backgrounds by the Openlayers plugin, `EPSG:3857` is the best choice for that.

Comment: I've added the CSV file and it's showing the locations in the south of Spain. I don't understand!

Comment: Have you mixed up latitude and longitude? The negative values of latitude should be Y, and the positive longitudes be X.